# Jquery incompatibility issue with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, incompatibility

I ran into a headache situation. When I checked the selection option (05/30/2012 EQ), I can't click select button to submit the action, but I am supposed to be able to click it. The issue  happens with Chrome and I.E, but it is good with FF. I think it is a Jquery incompatibility issue. I attached some of my code as follows:

```
  function $recalcSelection($checkbox) {
    $selectActionList.find("option").each(function() {
      $optionLength = $table.find("td.actioncolumn input:checked").length;
      if($optionLength <= 0) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
      } else if($optionLength == 1) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
      } else {
        if(
          $(this).val() == "editAppointment" ||
          $(this).val() == "copyAppointment" ||
          $(this).val() == "viewShowList" ||
          $(this).val() == "viewScheduledTimes")
        {
          $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
          $(this).attr("disabled", false);
        }
      }
    });

    if($selectActionList.find("option:selected").attr('disabled')) {
      $selectActionList.find("option:enabled").eq(0).attr("selected", true);
    }

    if($selectActionList.find("option:enabled").length <= 0) {
      $selectActionButton.attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $selectActionButton.attr("disabled", false);
    }
  }
```

$selectActionButton is the submit button, and $selectactionlist is the select list. I tried to print ($selectActionList.find("option:enabled").length in Chrome, it is 0. But when I was printing it in FF, it is 7. Can anyone help me to figure out why? I would so appreciate it. thanks

[image]

I attached some of the HTML table as follows:

```
<table id="appointmentTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headerrow">
      <th class="actioncolumn"></th>
      <th class="datecolumn">Date</th>
      <th class="earliesttimecolumn">Start Time</th>

      <th class="clientnamecolumn">Client</th>
      <th class="locationcolumn">Location</th>
      <th class="roomcolumn">Rooms</th>
      <th class="typecolumn">Type</th>
      <th class="filledtimescolumn">Filled Times</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody> 

      <tr class=" hiddenrow" appointmentid="15166">
        <td class="actioncolumn"><input type="checkbox" name="appointmentids[]" value="15166" /></td>
        <td class="datecolumn"><span title="1338094800"></span><a href="?action=viewDailyUsers&date=05/27/2012&clients[]=8" title="View Appointments on 05/27/2012">05/27/2012</a></td>
        <td class="earliesttimecolumn"></td>
        <td class="clientnamecolumn">CPH</td>
        <td class="locationcolumn">New Location</td>
        <td class="roomcolumn"></td>

        <td class="typecolumn">Screening</td>
        <td class="filledtimescolumn">0/0</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr class="actionrow">
      <td colspan="2" class="actioncolumn"></td>
      <td colspan="6">With Selected:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="actionrow">
                  <td colspan="2" class="actioncolumn">

        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Create New" />
      </td>
                  <td colspan="6">
        <select id="selectactionlist" name="selectaction">
                          <optgroup label="Adjustments">
            <option value="editAppointment">Edit</option>
            <option value="copyAppointment">Copy</option>
            <option value="deleteAppointment">Delete</option>

          </optgroup>
                          <optgroup label="Lists">
                              <option value="viewShowList">Show/No Show List</option>
                              <option value="viewScheduledTimes">Schedule List</option>
          </optgroup>
                          <optgroup label="Hidden">
            <option value="hideAppointment">Hide</option>

            <option value="showAppointment">Show</option>
          </optgroup>
                        </select>
        <input id="selectactionbutton" type="submit" name="button" value="Select" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
```

Comment: This `$(this).attr("disabled", false);` should be `$(this).prop("disabled", false);`

Comment: You'll need to post your HTML in order for this to make sense.

Comment: @asawyer whilst `prop` is better practice, it makes no different to the OP's question :)

Comment: @mattytommo I never said it did, just noticed it while reading through the question.

Comment: What is `$table`? Are you sure it's in scope?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is in the scope. It works perfect with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the following:

```
    if (foo) {
      $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    }
```

You should add and remove the disabled attribute, as sometimes just the presence of the disabled attribute can make it disabled (probably why chrome keeps it disabled). Try this instead:

```
if (foo) {
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
} else {
    $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

**EDIT: Try this exact code**

```
function $recalcSelection($checkbox) {
    $selectActionList.find("option").each(function() {
        $optionLength = $table.find("td.actioncolumn input:checked").length;
        if($optionLength <= 0) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        } else if($optionLength == 1) {
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            if($(this).val() == "editAppointment" ||
                $(this).val() == "copyAppointment" ||
                $(this).val() == "viewShowList" ||
                $(this).val() == "viewScheduledTimes")
            {
                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        }
    });

    if($selectActionList.find("option:selected").attr('disabled') != "true") {
        $selectActionList.find("option").filter(function () { return $(this).attr("disabled") != null}).eq(0).attr("selected", true);
    }

    if($selectActionList.find("option").filter(function () { return $(this).attr("disabled") != null}).length <= 0) {
        $selectActionButton.attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $selectActionButton.removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}​
```

Comment: Then wrap this up in an a tiny jQuery plugin abstraction for all your other controls.

Comment: Mattytommo, thanks for your answer, but it didn't fix it. I also try to replace attr with prop, and it didn't work either. I have no idea. confused

Comment: Sorry, I tried but still didn't work. $selectActionList.find("option:enabled").length is 0 in Chrome and 7 in FF, I think that is the issue

Comment: @庆峰 扈 Ahh yeah you're right, I've never seen `enabled` and I can't get that to work, try my new code in my edit, it replaces `enabled` with the `filter` function.

Comment: Hi Mattytommo.I really appreciate your help and patience. This solution didn't fix it either, and it didn't work in FF as well

Comment: @庆峰 扈 No problems, we'll get there! I'm trying to recreate your environment using the code you originally pasted, can you edit it to include where the js function is called? Here's the JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f45P8/ just press update when you're done and send me the link :)

Comment: Mattytommo, I added the entrance Jquery code. http://jsfiddle.net/f45P8/3/. Hope it would help, thanks

Comment: Hi Mattytommo. I figured out another way to solve the problem. Thanks so much for your help. Appreciate it:)

Comment: @庆峰 扈 Ah just curious, what was it that fixed it? I'd just ported it to Visual Studio and was going through it :)